# python dictionary : unorderable types error

Tags: python, gdb

I am adding a generic GDB pretty printer as described [here](https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/make-debugging-easier-with-custom-pretty-printers/) to my gdb, the following line adds the map of the types to use the printer:

```
pretty_printers_dict[re.compile ('.*Generic.*')] = GenericPrinter
```

I need to adapt it to my types:

```
pretty_printers_dict[re.compile ('MyNamespace1.*')] = GenericPrinter
pretty_printers_dict[re.compile ('MyNamespace2.*')] = GenericPrinter
```

Basically I like to use the printer for all my types.

But I get the following error inside gdb:

```
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> unorderable types: _sre.SRE_Pattern() < _sre.SRE_Pattern(): 
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> unorderable types: _sre.SRE_Pattern() < _sre.SRE_Pattern():
```

If I remove either line, it works fine. I am puzzled,

Do you see what problem it is and how to fix it?

[**UPDATE**]
I get away from it by combining the regular expressions:

```
pretty_printers_dict[re.compile ('MyNamespace1.*|MyNamespace2.*')] = GenericPrinter
```

Comment: Could you please provide more code, because that does not make sense. This should work and is working on my machine!

Comment: @my_question, if you got a working solution you should add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get away from it by combining the regular expressions:

```
pretty_printers_dict[re.compile ('MyNamespace1.*|MyNamespace2.*')] = GenericPrinter
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem only occurs in python 3:

The `sorted` function needs to compare the two compiled regexes wich does only work in python 2 (I don't know why).

But I do not think that the `sorted` call is necessary so just leave it out:

```
for function in pretty_printers_dict:
    if function.match(typename):
        return pretty_printers_dict[function](val)
```